# Angular project that reads from a large DB table not loading values properly when deployed to S3

Tags: angular, entity-framework, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a database that I have hosted using RDS. I have a table whose entries are basically just the names of around 2000 US universities. I have created a select statement that is supposed to show all these values.

When I run this locally (with just `ng serve`), it works, and the select box (probably) contains all the universities. However, when I deploy the Angular project to S3, what seems to happen is the values are loaded for about a second (I see the first one in the list pre-loaded), but then it quickly becomes a small, blank one, as though the variable that I have it binded to is `null`.

I did something similar with the US States/Territories, and the select box loads fine both locally and when deployed to S3

I'm not sure if this is really a code related problem, but if needed, please comment and let me know what should be seen. I would expect this to be some sort of RDS/Lambda/S3 configuration issue, but do not know where to start.

Comment: Perhaps you want to provide some snippets of your code and possibly some screenshots of your problem?

Comment: The place I would start is looking at the HTTP requests happening in the browser's developer console. In particular, look at the requests being made to load the data for that select box when you run things locally and it works. Then look at the same request happening when you load the app from S3 and see if there is some difference in the response your Angular app is receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I kind of figured out what I was doing wrong. I have a service that contains a list that I use to contain all the Universities. I initially had a method that makes the GET request, subscribes, and returns the response as a list, which I then assign to the service list. Instead of doing this, I made the method just assign the value of the response to the service list. This works on both local and S3.